# Grouping multiple columns and count from a DataFrame in Apache Spark - Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a csv file again (imported in hdfs hadoop) showing taxi routes, and the structure of it, is:

```
●taxi_id​ (eg, id109243)
●pickup_date (eg, 10/10/2019)
●passengers​ (eg, 3)
●pick_lon​ (eg, -70.0235)
●pick_lat​ (eg, 40.19091)
```

Now, i have many many rows , almost 1 million of these. And, i want to count the taxi routes per area and per day. By mean area, i just have spitted 4 areas (based lat and long), and i check every taxi route latitude and longitude to see if contained inside this area. So my results has to be something like this:

```
 Day1: 10/10/2019 -> There are 145 taxi routes from Quarter Area 1
 Day1: 10/10/2019 -> There are 156 taxi routes from Quarter Area 2
 Day1: 10/10/2019 -> There are 214 taxi routes from Quarter Area 3
 Day1: 10/10/2019 -> There are 200 taxi routes from Quarter Area 4
.....
 Day2: 11/10/2019 -> There are 145 taxi routes from Quarter Area 1
 Day2: 11/10/2019 -> There are 156 taxi routes from Quarter Area 2
 Day2: 11/10/2019 -> There are 214 taxi routes from Quarter Area 3
 Day2: 11/10/2019 -> There are 200 taxi routes from Quarter Area 4
.........
```

My Java Code [Java 8, Spark 2.4.4]

```
package com.bigdata.taxi;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.setAppName("My 1st Spark app");
        conf.setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().sparkContext(sc.sc()).getOrCreate();

        //Now read csv , from hdfs source
        //[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hdfs dfs -put /home/cloudera/Desktop/fares.csv hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020//user//cloudera//fares.csv
        Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.read().option("header", true).option("inferSchema", "true").
                option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").csv("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020//user//cloudera//fares.csv");
        //df.show(); //only showing top 20 rows
        //System.out.println(df.schema());

        //Add new column from the first dataframe, with only date.
        Dataset<Row> df_date_column = df.withColumn("pickup_date", date_format(col("pickup_datetime"), "yyyy-MM-dd"));
        //df_date_column.show();

        //Dataset<Row> df2 = df_date_column.groupBy("pickup_date").count();
        //df2.orderBy("pickup_date").show(182, false);

        //??
        df_date_column.foreach(row -> { 
            getCoordinates(row);
        });

        //System.out.println(df.schema());
    }

    /*private static void getCoordinates(Row r){
        //extract lon and lat from r
        //then see which quarter field belong
        double x = r.getDouble(5);
        double y = r.getDouble(6);
        System.out.println("To x einai : " + x);
        System.out.println("To y einai : " + y);

        if((40<=x && x<=56) && (-89<=y && y<=-56)){

        }else if((40<=x && x<=56) && (-89<=y && y<=-56)){

        }else if((40<=x && x<=56) && (-89<=y && y<=-56)){

        }else if((40<=x && x<=56) && (-89<=y && y<=-56)){

        }
    }*/
}
```

So, i have to group column pickup_date, but how can i check in every row, the latitude and longitude of taxi route and count it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `map` function

```java
Encoder enc = Encoders.bean(DateAndQuarter.class);
Dataset<DateAndQuarter> daq = df_date_column.map(row -> {
    String date = row.getAs("pickup_date");
    double x = r.getDouble(5);
    double y = r.getDouble(6);
    int quarter = 0;
    if((40<=x && x<=56) && (-89<=y && y<=-56)){
       quarter = 1;
    } else if((40<=x && x<=56) && (-89<=y && y<=-56)){
       quarter = 2;
    } else if((40<=x && x<=56) && (-89<=y && y<=-56)){
       quarter = 3;
    } else if((40<=x && x<=56) && (-89<=y && y<=-56)){
       quarter = 4;
    }
    DateAndQuarter retObj = new DateAndQuarter();
    retObj.date = date;
    retObj.quarter = quarter;
    return retObj;
}, enc);
...
public static class DateAndQuarter {
   private String date;
   private int quarter;
}
```

After that you can use groupBy and do any aggregation you want;